# get_posts returns all posts

Tags: get-posts

I am having some hard time figuring out why my `get_posts` function return all posts  instead of specific ones.

I have a post type called `mall`, in it a taxonomy called `shop` which have two terms `Compi` and `Macho`. In the variable `$store_name` one of these terms is stored (depending on the product which is in the order) and when I am using the variable in `terms` for the `$malls_args`, I am getting all the malls. Even those without the term stored in the variable `$store_name`.

I tried to hard-code the variable and used `"Copmi"` inside the `terms` but I am still getting all the malls.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'asdf_test' );
function asdf_test( $order ) {

    $dokanOrderManager = new Dokan_Order_Manager();

    $vendor_id = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_dokan_vendor_id', false )[0];

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $line_item ) {

        $prod =  $line_item->get_product();
        $prod_id = $prod->get_id();
        $author = get_user_by( 'id', $prod->post->post_author );
        $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $author->ID );
        $store_name = $store_info['store_name'];
        $store_address = $store_info['address']['street_1'] . ', ' . $store_info['address']['city'];
        $malls_args = array(
            "post_type" => "mall",
            "tax_query" => array(
                "taxonomy" => "shop",
                "field" => "name",
                "terms" => "Compi" // - - - - - - $store_name gives all posts too.
            )
        );

        $malls = get_posts( $malls_args );

        foreach ( $malls as $mall ) {
            echo $mall->ID . '<br/>';
        }

    }

}
```

Any idea? If anymore information is needed please tell me and I will do my best to provide it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correctly the `tax_query`argument. This argument takes array of tax query arguments arrays, to allow for complex queries with multiple taxonomies. You can learn more in the [WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

This is the correct way:

```
$malls_args = array(
    "post_type" => "mall",
    "tax_query" => array(
        array(
            "taxonomy" => "shop",
            "field" => "name",
            "terms" => "Compi" // - - - - - - $store_name gives all posts too.        
        ),
    )
);
```